# Mac Running OSX 10.6.8 - How to install FontForge?

Tags: macos, mac, installation

Where can I find an idiots guide to installing FontForge on my computer?  I'm looking for a guide that is step by step and doesn't assume that I know anything about classpaths or anything else technical.

Comment: If you want to avoid technical things, you can consider installing MacPorts or something similar

Comment: Thanks Andrea, that sounds a good solution.   Just one thing though, it needs Xcode to be installed.   I tried to get it from Apple.com but their version nolonger supports Snow Leopard (10.6).   I tried my original Install Disk but my machine rejects it (perhaps it is only good for an OpSys install?).   Do you know where I can download  a version of Xcode that will install on 10.6.8?    Thanks.

Comment: Okay I have Xcode installed and MacPorts.   I have an  xterm window open.   What exactly do I need to do to download and install FontForge?   FontForge suggests that MacPorts has a package that I can download but I don't see it (I can see a copy of a port file but it is not obvious what I need to actually do).  I have typed "sudo port install fontforge" on the command line incase MacPorts knows how to find and get it, but I just get Port fontforge not found.   So what do I actually have to do to make this work?   Thanks for your great assistance.

Comment: Did you update ports with `sudo port -v selfupdate`?

Comment: I didn't think it would be necessary as I'd only just installed MacPorts, but I did it anyway.   It seems that the MacPorts site is down: "rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)".  Did I do something wrong? Is there another site I can get the port from?  I have downloaded the relevant Portfile but I don't know where to place it or how to tell MacPorts to use it instead of looking elsewhere.   Thanks. Connor.

Comment: Honestly, I've never used a Portfile before, because my MacPorts updates fine, but I know that network settings can make upgrading very difficult or even impossibile. 

By the way, I found this how-to on MacPorts website: [link](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/Upgrade)

Comment: If it doesn't work (and you don't need features that are on FontForge only), you can still download and install an alternative to FontForge [like these](http://alternativeto.net/software/fontforge/)

Comment: Thanks Andrea, you're really helpful.   I have had a look at those other tools, but all of them have some catch, eg Apple developer tools I'm sure would work well but they don't work with .ttf . TypeLight deliberately will not allow you to copy glyphs between fonts.  There seem to be lots of commercial software and lots of very specific tools for font designers, but no simple tool for copying glyphs from one ttf font to another.  What would be nice would be a FontForge package for OSX 10.6.8 that someone has already successfully made, or someone willing to do the copying for me.  Connor.

Comment: I found this (I hope) [simple guide](http://www.davidlanier.com/blog/2012/1/how-to-install-fontforge-mac-os-x-lion-homebrew) on how to install FontForge. You have to work with terminal, but, as article says, I am afraid there are no easier ways to do it.